# BeforeSave event prompts a password asking userform twice

Tags: vba, excel

I want Excel asks me a password before saving. If the password is correct then save; if not shows an alert and does not save.

Here is the code I wrote which calls a userform to get the password which is a text box and two buttons as "OK" and "Cancel".

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim Password As String
    Dim InputPass As String
    Password = "MyPass"
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ""
    UserForm1.Show
    InputPass = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
    If InputPass = Password Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Else
        MsgBox ("Wrong password!")
        Cancel = True
    End If

    End Sub
```

The problem is that when I put in the correct password then it prompts the userform again. I don't want to get the userform again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `ActiveWorkbook.Save`, the workbook is already in the process of being saved. Only if you set `Cancel = True` will the workbook NOT be saved. Calling `.Save` triggers the event again.

Comment: I will also mention that it is not necessarily `ActiveWorkbook` that is currently being saved, `ThisWorkbook` is the safest reference in event code.

Comment: Does this workbook.save trigger a loop of saving? Then indeed just removing it should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes it does, I've now mentioned that in the answer. Ta.